# Событие клика на скроллах панели

Tags: c#, winforms, control-panel

У меня есть панель с элементами внутри нее, у панели есть скроллинг по горизонтали и вертикали. Событие OnScroll панели происходит, если кликнуть на ползунок и мышью таскать его туда-сюда, но если кликнуть мышью на полосу прокрутки где ползунка нет, то ползунок перемещается, но событие OnScroll не происходит, почему?

Answer (score 0):

У panel есть свойство  Scroll, оно возникает при любом клике по ползунку, стрелкам скролбара, а так же и по пустому месту.

Comment: вот такая ситуация, есть splitpanel на форме, в верхней части контрола есть внутри panel1. Мне необходимо сделать синхронный скролл нижней панели splitpanel и panel1. Т.Е. я хочу перемещать горизонтальный скролл нижней панели, после чего должен перемещаться горизонтальный сколл panel1.

Comment: В обработчике события сколла для нижней панели я проверяю, что скролл горизонтальный и устанавливаю новую позицию ползунка для panel1, и вот тут позиция не устанавливается и ошибка не возникает.

Comment: @Naf перенесите ваши комментарии в вопрос, для этого есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/678614/edit). Чем точнее описана проблема, тем быстрее сможете получить ответ.